# R KNN categorization with DocumentTermMatrixes

Tags: r

i'm giving first steps with R and now im testing the KNN classification method (package class), but im struggling to put it working.

I have two DocumentTermMatrix, one for train and another for test.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/218veow5tqrhlcw/train_test_matrix.png

i think im doing all right.

```
## Test KNN Classification
train = dtm_control_tfidf_treino # train set from 1:7
test = dtm_control_tfidf_teste   # test set from 8:10
cl = factor(dtm_control_tfidf_treino$class[1:7])
x = knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob = TRUE)
attributes(.Last.value)
```

i'm getting the error

```
> x = knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob = TRUE)
Error in knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob = TRUE) : 
'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

i'm really do not understand how make this work. if semeone could give me some hints how to do this process well would be nice.

if you need more data or wtv just ask

Comment: According to your data, `train` seems to contain 3 documents but you have 7 classes thus they have different lengths and you get an error. There should be a 1:1 mapping between the `cl` variable and the documents in the `train` object.

Comment: lool, what a noobie, i forgot change some code. till, i already made de changes:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/218veow5tqrhlcw/train_test_matrix.png

and now i've the error.


    Error in knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob = TRUE) : 
    dims of 'test' and 'train'

Comment: @andrealmeida post the results of head(test) and head(train) and dim(test) and dim(train).

Comment: That's the exact same picture, isn't it? What's different?

Comment: @AndrewCassidy head() doesn't work on DocumentTermMatrices

Comment: sorry, the new pic is this https://www.dropbox.com/s/cuybztmbz8wylab/train_test_matrix2.png

Comment: I'm confused now... @MrFlick doesn't knn in the class library expect data frames or matrices?

Comment: @AndrewCassidy yes, but i'm using matrices, and head() doesnt work on them

Comment: @AndrewCassidy I tried it and it cast the dtm to a matrix. A dtm is essentially a sparce matrix, but they choose not to overload the `head()` generic function.

Comment: This test case works just fine. `library(tm); data("crude"); dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude,control=list(stopwords = TRUE)); knn(dtm[16:20, ], dtm[1:15,], letters[1:5])` There must be something wrong with your data still. YOU need to create an example that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here my initial data https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdyrz7g165cxry5/data.txt and there my code (i know the code is not the best, but im still experiencing and exploring R) http://pastebin.com/9sD3EnGy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subset the corpus, each of the DTMs will have different words. This is not what you want. You want them to share a common term list. So instead, build the DTM with all documents, then subset the DTM to make the test/train sets. Here's an example using built in data sets.

```
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
cc<-VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578), list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))

dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(cc)

train<-dtm[1:7,]
test<-dtm[8:10,]

knn(train,test,factor(letters[1:7]), k=3, prob=T)
```

Comment: got it. Thnks for the patience.